# Realizing algebraic curves as complete intersections

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, complete-intersection

I have two related questions about smooth complete algebraic curves (over $\mathbb{C}$).

1. Does there exist a smooth complete algebraic curve $X$ that cannot be embedded as a complete intersection in $\mathbb{P}^n$ for any $n$ (nb: this is different from asking if every smooth curve in $\mathbb{P}^n$ is a complete intersection, which is of course false; e.g. the twisted cubic)?  I expect that the answer is "yes", though it might be "no" for specific genera (and I'd be interested in known these genera).  If you bounded $n$, then probably you could use the fact that the moduli space of curves is of general type for large genus to prove this.
2. Fix a genus $g$.  Does there exist some $n$ such that $\mathbb{P}^n$ contains a smooth genus $g$ curve as a complete intersection?  I'm not really sure if the answer should be yes or no; if it is no, then I'd be interested in knowing which $g$ satisfy this.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

1) The genus of a complete intersection of multidegree $(d_1,\ldots ,d_{n-1})$ in $\mathbb{P}^n$ is $g=1+\frac{1}{2} d_1\cdot \ldots \cdot d_{n-1}(\sum d_i-n-1)$ (just compute the degree of the canonical bundle). This gives very particular values for  $g$: $0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9, 10, 13, 15, 16,\dotsc $ . Any curve whose genus is not in this list cannot be realized as a complete intersection.

2) Even if $g$ is in that list, for $g>5$ a general curve of genus $g$ cannot be realized as a complete intersection, since the number of moduli of such  complete intersection is smaller than $3g-3$ (the number of moduli of a  general curve of genus $g$).

Comment: Thanks!  I feel a little foolish to have not realized (2)...

Comment: You write "$g=1,\ldots,5,9,10,12,16,\ldots$", but $g=2$ does not occur
(while $g=0$ of course does).

Comment: Yes. Sorry I went too fast!

Comment: Shouldn't 6 also be in that list, using a planar curve of degree 5? I also think 12 should not be in the list, whilst 13 should (using (3,2,2)) and so does 15 (as a curve of degree 7).

Comment: You are absolutely right. Sorry I didn't pay too much attention to the precise numbers -- I just wanted to indicate the principle.

Comment: There is now an entry in the OEIS giving the numbers up to a certain cutoff, see https://oeis.org/A266322.

Comment: The answer of abx of course also reveals that the canonical bundle of a c.i. curve of genus ≥ 2 is very ample, hence no hyperelliptic curve of any genus ≥ 2 can occur as a c.i.  This is just to illustrate explicitly the remark of abx that even among the allowable genera, exceptions exist.

Comment: Does the above-given equation for the genus hold only for polynomials that do not have singularity?

Comment: No, it is still valid for a singular curve $X$ if you have in mind the *arithmetic genus*, that is $\dim H^1(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$. For singular curves there is also the *geometric genus*, that is, the genus of the normalization of $X$; it is equal to the arithmetic genus minus the contribution of the singularities.

Comment: @Eoin: No, the computation of the canonical bundle does not necessitate any assumption on the hypersurfaces.