# Example of variety which is not a complete intersection with respect to any projective embedding

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, complex-geometry

Suppose $X$ is a smooth projective variety. Whether $X$ is a complete intersection or not when viewed as a subvariety of some projective space $\mathbb P^n$ is dependent on the specific choice of the projective embedding $X\hookrightarrow\mathbb P^n$. For example, taking $X=\mathbb P^1$, we can embed it into $\mathbb P^2$ and $\mathbb P^3$ as a conic and a twisted cubic respectively (the first is a complete intersection while the second one is not).

Is there a simple example of a smooth projective $X$ which is **not** a complete intersection with respect to **any** projective embedding $X\hookrightarrow\mathbb P^n$?

Comment: Curves of many genera are not realisable as complete intersections, see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/179688/realizing-algebraic-curves-as-complete-intersections.

Comment: A smooth variety of dimension $\ge 2$ which is a complete intersection must be simply connected by the Lefschetz hyperplane theorem, so you get lots of counterexamples (e.g., for abelian varieties).

Comment: Also a hyperelliptic curve of any genus $\ge 2$ works, since the canonical bundle of a complete intersection curve would be (very) ample.

Comment: [Complete intersections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_intersection) are a very special class of varieties. The Lefschetz hyperplane theorem gives strong restrictions on the cohomology of a complete intersection.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments, this answers my question.

Comment: Perhaps one of the commenters would like to leave an answer below?